# Unable to install Phonegap

Tags: node.js, cordova

I am trying to install phonegap on my mac using sudo npm install -g phonegap.
And i keep getting this errors:

```
npm ERR! TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'match'
npm ERR!     at Object.scriptpath_ (/Users/admin/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:138:23)
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at scriptpath (/Users/admin/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:132:19)
npm ERR!     at /Users/admin/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:119:33
npm ERR!     at Array.forEach (native)
npm ERR!     at extras (/Users/admin/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:118:21)
npm ERR!     at parseJson (/Users/admin/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:87:17)
npm ERR!     at /Users/admin/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:59:33
npm ERR!     at fs.js:266:14
npm ERR!     at /Users/admin/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:103:5
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.5.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/admin
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.23
npm ERR! type undefined_method
```

And:

```
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/admin/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your npm that's the command on macOSX `npm -g install npm@latest`